# Why is pod not found? Error from server (NotFound): pods "curl-pod" not found

Tags: kubernetes

I can list pods in my prod namespace

```
kubectl get pods -n prod
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
curl-pod   1/1     Running   1 (32m ago)   38m
web        1/1     Running   1 (33m ago)   38m
```

I got error

```
kubectl describe pods curl-pod
Error from server (NotFound): pods "curl-pod" not found
```

Get events show

```
   Normal   Scheduled        pod/curl-pod   Successfully assigned prod/curl-pod to minikube
```

Why?

Comment: Perhaps you are not searching the correct namespace? `kubectl describe pods curl-pod -n  prod`. Not specifying a namespace usually searches in the default namespace and your pod is in the prod namespace so this might be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kubernetes manages by namespace, so you must specify namespace otherwise kubernetes will use namespace default.
So, you must type:

```
kubectl describe pod/curl-pod -n prod
```